# What is a sweet pain, exactly?

Tags: cognitive-psychology, sensation

Why some pains are sweet? Some pains give pleasure not even bodily pains but mentally also in daily affairs, an individual may intentionally impose mild difficulties on his self. Is there a cognitive or evolutionary reason behind it or it is a disorder?

Answer (score 2):

[Endorphins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endorphins) and [flow experience](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flow_experience) I suppose. Seems adaptive enough to have some mechanism for overcoming short-term distress for the sake of long-term gains, but like most things, this can be taken to extremes. There's some debate regarding the status of [masochism](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sadism_and_masochism_as_medical_terms) within the normal–abnormal spectrum. See also [internalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internalization), which [includes](http://bpd.about.com/od/glossary/g/Internalizing.htm) [self-harm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-harm) among other forms of [maladaptation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maladaptation).

Answer (score 0):

According to [Applied system-vector psychoanalysis](https://www.psy8.net/pages/about) masochism happens among people with dominant "[dermal vector](https://www.psy8.net/chapters/orange-vector-skin)" who have been endured painful physical punishments in childhood.